# Third Party SDK won't read imports, even when the dependency is in the Build Gradle

Tags: java, android, build.gradle, android-bluetooth

I had imported a Third party SDK from another project. I had set it up and it wouldn't read a certain Dependency, even when I had put the dependency in the build gradle.

Here's the SDK
[image]

And in the build.gradle

```
   // dependency needed to use SDK
    implementation "org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.16.3" <- That's the dependency
    implementation project(':parabit_beacon_sdk')
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:20.1.0'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1"
```

I've tried a few things already, but nothing seems to be working. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no version 2.16.3 of `org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library` in Maven central repository:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.altbeacon/android-beacon-library

Unless you have configured an additional repository where this library is present, Android Studio can simply not resolve this library and thus the import statements for this library show an error.

Note that JCenter repository does no longer exists. The version you want to use was once published there but as the repository no longer exists you can not use it anymore from there.

Change your gradle config to use a version that exists on Maven central.

Comment: You were absolutely correct. I didn't check the maven repo to see if it exist. Thank You.